# How do I collect 1000 recent tweets of lot of users(say 80000) from twitter?

Tags: twitter, bigdata, information-retrieval

I am trying to collect 1000 recent tweets of lot of users (around 80000) for my research work. I tried using REST API but due to rate limit its becoming not practical for 80000 users. Lot of Research papers said they have collected tweets and other information of thousands of users but i could not figure out how did they do. WHat is the best way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Twitter Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public).

You will be able to get real-time tweets from everyone.  You can filter it down with search parameters if you want.

Comment: I have a set of 80000 users and I want to collect 1000 recent tweets of them. I dont its possible with Straming API.

Comment: What, if I may ask, is so special about those 80,000?

Comment: I am actually doing some classification task and these 80,000 users are my labelled training data.

Comment: You can request 200 status updates per API call, and you're rate limited to 180 requests per 15 minutes.  That's 1,000 tweets from 36 users per 15 minutes.  It will take you about 560 hours (24 days) to get all that data.  Your only other option is to set up a bunch of machines to make the requests in parallel.

Comment: I have tried that already. Wanted to know if there is a way which takes less time.